# Windows 10 UWP MapControl moved event

Tags: xaml, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

When the user is manually moving the map, I'd like to evaluate some criteria and optionally do something when they're finished. I can't seem to find the right [MapControl event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.aspx#events) to hook into for this.

I've tried using [CenterChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.centerchanged.aspx), but it fires constantly while the map is moving and degrades performance.

Which `MapControl` event can I use to know when the user has finished moving the map?

Comment: You might use the ManipulationCompleted event. Otherwise a typical approach would be to stop and restart a timer in a CenterChanged handler, and do the final processing in the timer's Tick handler.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried using ManipulationCompleted previously but the event never fires. Do you have an example of the timer approach?

Comment: You have to set the ManipulationMode to a value other than None or System, e.g. to All. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationcompleted.aspx).

Comment: I saw that too. Didn't make any difference. The event never fires.

Comment: I remember something about that in WP with Here, I'll take a look

Comment: Well I tried but I refuse to continue when I set IsHitTestVisible and stills moving. This control does not follow any Control rule, The only approach I did is setting  Window.Current.CoreWindow.SetPointerCapture(); but it is like it is a DirectX and goes by its way, even tried to edit the template but literally explodes  VS and Blend

Comment: Check the LoadingStatusChanged event. See @S.Matthews answer for complete solution.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm about a year too late on this, but in case anyone runs into this question... I'm pretty sure the right way to do this is to listen to the [LoadingStatusChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn637028) event, then take action when you get back [MapLoadingStatus.Loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.maploadingstatus).

```
public void LoadingStatusChangedEventHandler(MapControl sender, Object o)
{
    if (sender.LoadingStatus == MapLoadingStatus.Loaded)
    {
        // The map has stopped moving and finished rendering
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I know the documentation for that event isn't great, but there's a little more information at [this code sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-maps#handle-user-interaction-and-changes), and you may be able to find even more on the [git repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl).

Comment: This is the best solution. Exactly what I needed. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a timer to check the map center every second and update my view model accordingly. It feels like a hack to me but it's much more performant than using `CenterChanged`. The `DispatchTimer` is used to allow the timer to run on the UI thread so it has access to the `MapControl`.

```
DispatcherTimer mapCenterTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
mapCenterTimer.Tick += (object sender, object e) =>
{
  ViewModel.MapCenter = MyMapControl.Center;
};
mapCenterTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // fire every second
mapCenterTimer.Start();
```

It sure would be nice if the MapControl exposed some sort of ManualMoveComplete event for those of us who want to take action when a user has finished moving the map. I've created a request for it here on uservoice: https://binglistens.uservoice.com/forums/283355-ideas/suggestions/9494889-add-a-centermanuallychanged-event-to-mapcontrol

Answer (score -1):

As I would agree with you that I'd prefer some kind of delayed event, I also prefer verbose controls and rather filter the events myself. From your solution, instead of firing a periodic timer every second, just restart it when the event fires. When the event stops firing, the timer will tick and you'll get the final value:

```
DispatcherTimer mapCenterTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
mapCenterTimer.Tick += (object sender, object e) =>
{
  mapCenterTimer.Stop();
  ViewModel.MapCenter = MyMapControl.Center;
};
mapCenterTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500); // map idle for .5 seconds
MyMapControl.CenterChanged += (map, args) => { mapCenterTimer.Stop(); mapCenterTimer.Start(); };
```